# What is the Maximum number of messages a queue can have in oracle AQ?

Tags: oracle, jms, oracle-aq

Hi I am using Oracle AQ for jms requirement. Is there any attribute that I can set while creating a queue that specifies the maximum number of messages that a Queue can have?

Also what is the default maximum number of messages a queue can have?

Comment: 1) No 2) No. AQ is normal table and there is no limit for it. Moreove if you set queue parameter  `retention_time = INFINITE` , all processed message will stay in queue.

Comment: What you should have is a way to count the number of messages, and if they reach the limit, do not insert more